# Showing a message from an async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am doing data fetch from net in an external task.
Now this fetch happens in two steps. So I want to display some message after the first step.

This will happen in the async task not on the UI task.
On the main UI task I already have a progress bar in the preexecute method.
I would like to know if there is a way to display something from the background async task.

I saw handle to be used for threads. Do we have something similar for async task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Override the `onProgressUpate` Method of your AsyncTask. There you can do the stuff to Display the Text.
To trigger onProgressUpdate you have to call `publishProgress()` in your `doInBackground`-Method.

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTask has an onProgressUpdate method which runs on the UI thread. Couldn't you use that somehow?